# Modelagem de banco de dados Dúvida PF e PJ

Tags: modelagem

Eu tenho um sistema que possui uma tabela chamada cliente, mas este cliente pode ser Pessoa física ou Pessoa Jurídica, neste caso para não criar uma tabela para cada um do tipo de cliente PF e PJ, até porque eu tenho relacionamento com outras tabelas como eu crio no sistema uma tabela dessas? Pois se eu crio na mesma, haverá momentos que algum campo poderá ficar vazio.

Comment: Na verdade o melhor é fazer um PF e um PJ que herda atributos de herança de um entidade pessoa.

Comment: o mais correto seria criar uma tabela para cada ao meu ver, pois Pessoa Fisica tem atributos diferentes de Pessoa Juridica, como CPF para um é CNPJ para outro, RG para um é Inscrição Estadual para outra, data de nascimento para um é data de fundação / criação para outro, e assim por diante. Crie uma classe pai pessoa e faça delas classes filhas extendendo os atributos necessários